# unknown column error in mysql after insert/update trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have two tables in the schema foo named as credit and credit_customers.
both look like:

```
**credit:**
creditId: primary key
partyId
creditedAmt
debitedAmt
```

and

```
**credit_customers:**
customer_id: primary key
balanceOutstanding
```

I tried creating a after update trigger on the credit table so that the balanceOutstanding column gets auto updated as balanceOutstanding = creditAmt-debitedAmt
The trigger created is as:
DELIMITER $$

```
USE `foo`$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `foo`.`creditAfterUpdateTrigger`
AFTER UPDATE ON `foo`.`credit`
FOR EACH ROW
update foo.credit_customers
    set balanceOutstanding = credit.NEW.creditedAmt - credit.NEW.debitedAmt
    where credit_customers.customer_id = credit.partyId$$
```

The trigger is created successfully . However when i try to upadate the credit table i get this error:

```
ERROR 1054: Unknown column 'partyId' in 'where clause'
SQL Statement:
UPDATE `foo`.`credit` SET `debitedAmt`=20000 WHERE `creditId`='5'
```

I am unable to get the cause of this error and how to debug it.
Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You need to join the `credit` table in the UPDATE statement

Comment: thanks a lot @juergend.  Is this because the where clause works backwards ?

Comment: Does `update foo.credit_customers
    set balanceOutstanding = NEW.creditedAmt - NEW.debitedAmt
    where customer_id = NEW.partyId` work for you? The trigger is created successfully because only syntax is checked at that time.

Comment: thanks again..got it :)